# Copy constructor C++ does not copy pointer correctly

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy

I created a copy constructor for my class. Does any one know why `l1.ptr` and `l2.ptr` give me the same address after compilation? I've done it many times and don't know where the error is.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class numb
{
public:
    int* ptr;
    numb(int = 3);
    numb(const numb&);
    virtual ~numb();
};

numb::numb(int x)
{
    this->ptr = new int(x);
}

numb::numb(const numb& l1)
{
    this->ptr = new int(*(l1.ptr));

}

numb::~numb()
{    
}

int main()
{
    numb l1(5), l2;
    l1 = l2;
    cout << l1.ptr << endl;
    cout << l2.ptr << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to provide a copy assignment operator (`numb& operator=(numb const&)`, read [CppCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c21-if-you-define-or-delete-any-default-operation-define-or-delete-them-all).

Comment: Copy construction would be something like `numb l2 = l1;`. With `l2 = l1;` you have copy *assignment*.

Comment: Remember the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You’re missing copy assignment: `operator=()`

Comment: And is this just some fooling around for curiosity, or do you really have code like this? Then why the pointer? What is the actual problem you try to solve by using pointer to a single `int`? Even if you have arrays, why use pointers and manual memory management instead of `std::vector`? And please learn about [the rules of three, five and zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). I highly recommend the rule of zero.

Comment: You meant `l2 = l1`, not `l1 = l2`, right?

Answer (score 4):

In this snippet:

```
numb l1(5), l2;
l2 = l1;
```

the second line is not calling the copy constructor. Instead, it is calling the copy-assignment operator. Since you have not defined that, you get a shallow copy.

You can either use the copy constructor, like this:

```
numb l1(5);
numb l2(l1);
```

or define the `operator=` for your class:

```
numb& operator=(const numb&);  // do a deep copy
```

Comment: Also there's no useful default constructor so the OP _probably_ meant `l2 = l1` not `l1 = l2`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Oops, good catch. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By not providing an assignment operator, you get the one that the compiler generates for you. The compiler is indeed "copying the pointer" (usually referred to as 'shallow copy').

If you need to copy the *pointee* (usually referred to as 'deep copy'), then you have to implement your own assignment operator.